# Extracting elements from an array to draw a rectangle

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

Aiming to plot four rectangles whose parameters are available in two arrays.

I found out a method using the array.map() function.

However, is there any function or faster way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

```
let arr1=[{x:20, y:50, l:100, h:30},{x:220, y:250, l:100, h:30}];
let arr2=[{x:30, y:100, l:5, h:30},{x:320, y:350, l:100, h:30}]


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  let arr_x = arr1.map(a => a.x).concat(arr2.map(a => a.x));
  let arr_y = arr1.map(a => a.y).concat(arr2.map(a => a.y));
  let arr_l = arr1.map(a => a.l).concat(arr2.map(a => a.l));
  let arr_h = arr1.map(a => a.h).concat(arr2.map(a => a.h));

  for(let i=0; i<arr_x.length; i++){
    rect(arr_x[i], arr_y[i], arr_l[i], arr_h[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why not just use `rect(arr1[i].x, arr1[i].y, arr1[i].l, arr1[i].h)`.  You can just concat arr1 and arr2.  Mapping isn't really necessary, and doesn't make the code more readable.

Comment: First, I tried it this way but is gave me this error: TypeError: arr1.x is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with one call to `concat` (or spread) and one `forEach` loop.

```js
let arr1=[{x:20, y:50, l:100, h:30},{x:220, y:250, l:100, h:30}];
let arr2=[{x:30, y:100, l:5, h:30},{x:320, y:350, l:100, h:30}];


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  [...arr1, ...arr2].forEach(({x , y, l, h}) => rect(x, y, l, h));
  
  // arr1.concat(arr2).forEach(({x , y, l, h}) => rect(x, y, l, h));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objects always have properties in that order, you call `Object.values` and spread into the `rect` call:

```js
const rect = console.log;

let arr1=[{x:20, y:50, l:100, h:30},{x:220, y:250, l:100, h:30}];
let arr2=[{x:30, y:100, l:5, h:30},{x:320, y:350, l:100, h:30}]

function draw() {
  for (const obj of arr1.concat(arr2)) {
    rect(...Object.values(obj));
  }
}
draw();
```

Or, without relying on property order:

```js
const rect = console.log;

let arr1=[{x:20, y:50, l:100, h:30},{x:220, y:250, l:100, h:30}];
let arr2=[{x:30, y:100, l:5, h:30},{x:320, y:350, l:100, h:30}]

function draw() {
  for (const obj of arr1.concat(arr2)) {
    rect(obj.x, obj.y, obj.l, obj.h);
  }
}
draw();
```